# Can't auth cluster with PCS with two nodes on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, cluster

Two nodes:

- 192.168.0.1
- 192.168.0.2

Both of them installed and started:

```
yum install pacemaker pcs
passwd hacluster
(Set the same password)
systemctl enable pcsd.service
systemctl start pcsd.service
```

When authenticating the cluster nodes:

```
(On node 1)
psc cluster auth 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2
(Output)
Username: hacluster
Password:
Error: Unable to communicate with 192.168.0.2
192.168.0.1: Authorized
```

Why can't authenticate node2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is didn't set right hostname in `/etc/hosts`.

```
192.168.0.1 node1
192.168.0.2 node2
```